# ejs issue "data.result.forEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a results.ejs site that I try to get the results of an api callback. In the ejs I have the following:

```
<h1>Results Page!!</h1>

<%data["result"].forEach(function(data){%>
<li><%= data["address"]%></li>
<% }) %>
```

Here the value is supposed to be taken from app.js that includes the api key its which works just parsing the body etc:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var KEY = process.env.token;

var menuSearch = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://us-restaurant-menus.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/zip_code/61603",
  // url: "https://us-restaurant-menus.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/search/portillos",
  qs: { page: "1" },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "us-restaurant-menus.p.rapidapi.com"
  }
};

app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
  request(menuSearch, function(error, response, body) {
    // console.log(body);

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      // res.send(data)
      // res.send(data["result"]["data"][0]["address"]["city"])
      res.render("results", { data: data });
    }
  });
  // res.send("Hello, it works!");
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("running on port: " + port);
});
```

now in the end the output gives me:

```
    1| <h1>Results Page!!</h1>
    2| 
 >> 3| <%data["result"].forEach(function(data){%>
    4| <li><%= data["address"]%></li>
    5| <% }) %>
    6| 

data.result.forEach is not a function...
```

can someone let me know where it's disconnected?

I'm thinking the key should be in the URL itself, though the key is already in the header. I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes `data["result"]` is an array, but it is not. How do I know this? `.forEach()` requires an array to work. If it's used on something other than an array, you get that message.

You called `res.render('results', {data: data})`

Without knowing for sure, I guess your `data` object is fairly complex. This commented-out line:

```
  res.send(data["result"]["data"][0]["address"]["city"])
```

makes it look like there's an array at `data.result.data`. (The giveaway is the index `[0]`.) If that's true your ejs code should say

```
<%data.result.data.forEach(function(item){%>
<li><%= item.address%></li>
<% }) %>
```

I changed `function(data)` to `function(item)`, because otherwise the `data` parameter name in the function invocation [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the name `data` from its caller, and that's just confusing.

You can find out your `data` object's structure by doing `console.log(data)` and looking at the output, or you can read the docs for the api.

Comment: Great explanation, answered my question. Thanks!